React library for noice/eco suppression
I created an app that interacts with a bot. The problem I'm facing is that when the bot talks, it listens to itself, causing it to loop. Is there any library that can help me with this?
Thanks!
I used getUserMedia() from the navigator object, but it doesn't seem to work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
